# how to set participant(type and id) for news feed entry in pfeed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, feed

hi i am using [pfeed](https://github.com/parolkar/pfeed/wiki) for generating news feed in my project.
how can i set value of  participant  id and type while generating feed entry.
i do not want to change plugin code.i need to change/(add some code) in model to achieve this functionality
pfeed has an entry for participant id and type in pfeed_item table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first argument is participant for feed entry.this should be AR object...so passing current_user to as first argument  to method(which generate) feed will set participant.

```
b=Book.find 2
b.checkout current_user
```

if checkout is registered for generating feed in pfeed then participant will be set
but how to pass current user if we want to generate feed with AR base class methods like generate feed for book update

```
b.update_attribute :name,"new name"
```

one solution is to override or add new method for update which will registered to generate feed and this method calls base method..like

```
  class Book <<AR::Base

  def update user,...
    self.update_attribute(s) ...
  end
```

now add this method to generate feed in book class

```
   emits_pfeeds :on=>[:update,...]
```